# postfix can't connect with mysql table when using unix socket. postmap succeeds though?

Tags: mysql, postfix-mta

Postfix is throwing up an error saying:

> Jul  9 14:41:26 tmail postfix/trivial-rewrite[4342]: warning: connect
>   to mysql server unix:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock: Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>   Jul  9 14:41:26 tmail postfix/trivial-rewrite[4342]: fatal:
>   mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-yaa-aliases.cf(0,lock|fold_fix): table lookup
>   problem

In main.cf I have:

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-yaa-aliases.cf
```

In mysql-yaa-aliases.cf I have:

```
hosts = unix:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = yaa_admin
password = ********
dbname = yaa
query = SELECT dest FROM yaa_active_aliases WHERE address='%s'
```

If I use 127.0.0.1 it works (not ideal as I would prefer the speed of a socket.)  Also if I test the socket with postmap it works:

```
# postmap -q "bholly@example.org" mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-yaa-aliases.cf
bholly@example.org, bholly@autoreply.example.org
```

When I use strace on the trivial-rewrite daemon I get:

```
connect(11, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Whereas strace using postmap I get:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, 110) = 0
```

BTW - Currently running Postfix 2.7, but the fault still shows with 2.9

Comment: BTW postmap tests succeed with both unix: and 127.0.0.1 lines

Answer (score 13):

FOUND IT :) - trivial-rewrite takes place in a chroot jail, therefore the socket file REALLY doesn't exist.

The solution (thanks to https://serverfault.com/questions/229389 for helping me with this) is to add this to the /etc/fstab:

```
/var/run/mysqld /var/spool/postfix/var/run/mysqld bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

Thus allowing Postfix to keep its chroot config, and giving it access to the mysql socket.

Comment: How about using as `host` value `127.0.0.1`? It helped me to solve this issue. It uses TCP connection which doesn't write socket (unlike `localhost` value on unix).

Comment: I think using a TCP connection is a better solution. Would be worthy of being a separate answer to this question. EDIT: I see, the question's closed. Oh well, I got my answer ;-)

Comment: @pevik I am trying to use 127.0.0.1 but still get the error Can't connect to MySQL server on <my_ip_address> . Any pointers?

Comment: @pevik Very old comments, but worth answering.  When both methods are possible, unix sockets are always preferable.  There was a time when it would be considered wrong to use TCPIP over unix sockets for a local connection.  Today CPUs are fast enough that more people use that shortcut. But engaging the TCP/IP stack for local connections is still wasteful and even with some localhost shortcuts in the system still adds significant overhead.  https://jasonbarnabe.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mysql-connections-sockets-vs-tcp/